# WEB APPLICATION OR PAGE SPEED TESTER [OR TEST TOOL]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, optimization, web

Is there a browser add-on or application that can use to test the speed of web applications?

If there is an existing tools like this. 
What do you use to check the speed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to checking page load times, you can simply use google chrome developer tools and check how much time being taken to load each resource and whole document and also you can below mentioned chrome extensions/add-ons to have better view of those statistics:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-load-time/fploionmjgeclbkemipmkogoaohcdbig?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/performance-analyser/djgfmlohefpomchfabngccpbaflcahjf?hl=en

As you might know already, developer tools are available in all the major browsers through which you can check the page load times (Network tab)

Edit:
Some tools which you can use:

https://speedcurve.com/

https://github.com/SOASTA/boomerang

https://tools.pingdom.com/

if you are using google analytics: http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/web-analytics/social-media-metrics/how-to-track-page-load-times-with-a-metrics-tool/

Comment: I am trying to look for tools to use on how I can test the page load and response of the application anyway I will try the following chrome extensions, this will be helpful. thank you.

Comment: Added some links to the tools you were mentioning, in the answer above. Thanks